# How to join the World of Programming?

Tags: programming-practices

Name's Vlad and I am currently on my third year of Community College, studying Computer Science with emphasis on Programming in C++ and Networking. I have completed a few programming courses with general ease, but have not gained advanced understanding of programming through school. None of my friends are serious programmers working in the industry.

Being an active lurker on many programming websites, and in general tech oriented sites I have noticed how little I know about the industry, the lingo and terminology. (I have no clue how Git hub works, but I generally understand what its for). So I am looking for help as to where I should look for information on the programming world and the industry in which I a very interested. By that I mean, what sites I should utilize to gain information on programming practices, introduction to advanced C++ and resources that simply introduce a 20some programming noob. I like programming, but I haven't dug my hands deep into it yet, I want to start to do so before I transfer to a University. All in all, where do I find information on becoming an actual programmer (Information that lays out a path).

Comment: Program as much as you can: challenge yourself with different interesting non-trivial problems and applications. Practice, practice and practice. What comes to source of information, there are a lot of nice books (I'm sure you'd find many links on http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Find a problem that you have, or a cool idea that you want to be realized, and make them happen.

Comment: Your enthusiasm is admirable, but this question is off topic.

Comment: @Ryathal well if that is true, where should I ask a question like this? This is precisely my issue.

Comment: @superM I have many books I am in the progress of reading (Around 200 Programming books). But besides reading and programming is there anything else I need to do/research to become a good, efficient programmer?

Comment: I would get a Java certification and find a job. Java is the easiest of languages and the most sought after by employers. Working with better programmers is the fastest way to learn. Read whatever you enjoy reading, you'll figure it out along the way.

Comment: @litebread you could try asking a question on the workplace about getting experience when you have no experience, or they may have one already

Comment: My two cents, as an addendum to the oft suggested "Get better by programming": Come up with a somewhat simple task that seems enjoyable. Let's say, make a simple game (text adventure, whatever). You'll naturally run into problems as you add more features, which will get you to search for answers to your practical problems. Sometimes the hardest problem is knowing what questions to ask or resources to look for. It worked wonders helping me get comfortable with Ruby (and by extension Regexps), and ease me into Scala/Haskell.

Comment: @litebread, I think you're on the right way. And as it was already advised, try to find a job. You can learn a lot from other programmers )))

Comment: You need to figure out what kind of programming you want to do (web sites or little robots that do stuff in factories). Based on that pick a language and start trying to get experience. So if your answer was websites try building a small ecommerce website for some local business.

Answer (score 3):

Start by creating your own **little projects**, creating new things everyday would help you **gain confidence and hand-on practice** with programming language/frameworks that you use.

Also look and learn from open-source projects which are hosted free for curious  programmers. They would really help you understand on how to use best practices while doing your coding and how decide on design. In addition, try to get involved in open-source project development, it will boost your self-learning and improvement dramatically.

Even-though you are a beginner/newbie programmer, you may get up-to speed on what skills are in demand for programmers. I would recommend to attend local community events to help with that. You may find some of these groups in [communitymegaphone.com](http://www.communitymegaphone.com/).

Talk with local buddy programmers, they are mostly good people who would not mind to help a college.

Answer (score 2):

Take what you know and figure out a problem you think you can solve with your programming skills. then expand that program to do a little bit more, using Google to help fill in the blanks and then if you get stumped [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.StackOverflow.com) or [Programmers.stackexchange.com](http://Programmers.stackexchange.com) for specific questions.

Read one book at a time. on one subject at a time, otherwise you may get confused.  there are languages that work together but they are not the same, they function differently.

Answer (score 1):

Build a personal website from scratch, find some small open-source projects and try to contribute and most important READ READ READ.  Read lots of books. This will get you half way home.